# want to add to my full calendar the holiday details

Tags: ajax, json, fullcalendar

I have implemented the fullCalendar and the events are getting displayed too from the database. 
I want to do the same for another holidays table.
Im posting my code here.

```
package net.admin.module.view;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import net.admin.module.controller.EventManager;
import net.admin.module.controller.HolidaysManager;
import net.admin.module.model.Event;
import net.admin.module.model.Holidays;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class EventAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9149826260758390091L;
    private Event event;
    private List<Event> eventList;
    private int id;
    private Holidays holidays;
    private List<Holidays> holidaysList;
    private HolidaysManager holidaysManager;
    private EventManager eventManager;
    public EventAction() {
        eventManager = new EventManager();
    }
    public String execute() {
        this.eventList = eventManager.list();
        System.out.println("execute called");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String eventAjax() {
        this.eventList = eventManager.list();
       // this.holidaysList = holidaysManager.list();
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();

        try{
            JSONObject jObject = null;
            Event event = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
                event = eventList.get(i);
                jObject=new JSONObject();
                jObject.put("title", event.getName());
                jObject.put("start", event.getDate());
                jObject.put("allDay", true);
            //  jObject.put("end", event.getDate());
                jArr.put(jObject);
            }
            json.put("eventdata", jArr);
            request.setAttribute("json", jArr);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "json";
    }

    public String addEvent() {
        System.out.println(getEvent());
        try {
            Event eve = getEvent();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                eve.setDate(df.parse(eve.getDateStr()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            eventManager.addEvent(eve);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String delete() {
        eventManager.deleteEvent(getId());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
    public List<Event> getEventList() {
        return eventList;
    }
    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
    public void setEventList(List<Event> eventList) {
        this.eventList = eventList;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Holidays getHolidays() {
        return holidays;
    }
    public List<Holidays> getHolidaysList() {
        return holidaysList;
    }
    public void setHolidays(Holidays holidays) {
        this.holidays = holidays;
    }
    public void setHolidaysList(List<Holidays> holidaysList) {
        this.holidaysList = holidaysList;
    }
    public HolidaysManager getHolidaysManager() {
        return holidaysManager;
    }
    public void setHolidaysManager(HolidaysManager holidaysManager) {
        this.holidaysManager = holidaysManager;
    }
}
```

This is my action class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media = "all"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='cssdata/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<pre>
<script>
var eventData = [];
$(document).ready(function() {

        //getEvents();
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'eventAjax.action',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                        start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                        end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
                    },
                    success: function(doc) {
                        var events = [];
                        $(doc).each(function() {
                            events.push({
                                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                                start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                            });
                        });
                        callback(events);
                    }
                });
            } 
        });

    });

    /* function getEvents(){
        $.post("eventAjax.action", {},
          function(data){
            eventData=data;
            alert(eventData);
        });
    } */                
</script>
<style>
    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my jsp.
The calendar shows all the events that are present in tha database as of now. I want to do the same with my holiday table.

Comment: What's the problem then ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another action class and add multiple [event sources](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) to full calendar like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param1: 'something',
                custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```